# How can I create a filter that filter values "generated" by a measure on a visual table on Power BI? Is it possible?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following visual table on Power BI.

[image]

- **%Sold o/ Estimated**
- **Word**

Were a `MEASURES` and calculated line by line on visual table, I don't have  **%Sold o/ Estimated** and **Word** on my database.

**Word** shows 2 values only. "Nice" for **%Sold o/ Estimated** between 100% and 51% and "Bad" between 50% and 0%.

I need to create a filter (Slicer) that contains the 2 words ("Nice" and "Bad") and when user choose "Nice", the table only shows de lines with **Word** = "Nice".

I can't set "Nice" and "Bad" for **Subcategorys** on database, its calculated by a measure on visual table.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table of the words you want to use in the slicer. You can input it using Enter Data or defining a new table like this:

```
Labels = DATATABLE("Words", STRING, {{"Nice"}, {"Bad"}})
```

In any case, it's just this simple table:

```
Words
-----
Nice
Bad
```

Use that column to create your slicer and then adjust your `Word` measure to take into account the slicer selection(s). For example, if your measure was

```
Word = IF([%Sold o/ Estimated] > 0.5, "Nice", "Bad")
```

then let's modify it so it returns blank when the output isn't one of the selected words.

```
Word = 
VAR Label = IF([%Sold o/ Estimated] > 0.5, "Nice", "Bad")
RETURN IF(Label IN VALUES(Labels[Words]), Label, BLANK())
```

This will make unselected words return blanks in your table. The final step is to add a *visual level filter* so that rows with blank `Word` values are excluded.

[image: Visual Level Filter]

Comment: Hey man, thanks for answer! 
I have a question: I dont need relate the tables? The table `Labels` and the `Other`?

Comment: Nope. There's nothing to relate them on anyway since the `Word` measure is not a column.